# Wind tunnel smoke generator

Tags: electrical-engineering

I need some sort of a smoke generator for a small wind tunnel. I have been thinking of making a system that pumps smoke fluid trough a small metal tube wand which has a heating coil at the end of it to vaporize the fluid. The same kind of setup is used in some commercial systems, but as they are too expensive I would like to build my own. I have some electronics experience as a hobbyist.

My question is that what kind of an coil should I use? Some sort of soldering iron heating element?

I think a heating element with a hole in the middle would be ideal, but i haven't seen one.

Comment: Consider a vape pen or a discotheque smoke machine depending on volume required. Alternatively check out the [Monster fog machine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpGjBgnpZC8&t=422s).

Comment: I'd use a propane insect fogger for a prototype. You can figure out what sort of fogging oil smokes best. Probably not the mosquito oil. https://www.walmart.com/ip/Burgess-Propane-Insect-Fogger-16443652N/19887356